# Where are the web apis in the client side "located"?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api

I know that there are web API's for both the server and client side. Where on the server the API consists of one more endpoints exposed via the web which runs over HTTP.

But what about the web api's on the client side? For the server side web api's we write them in some language (Javascript, Java, python, etc.) but on the client side the web api's (such as `setTimeout`, `XMLHTTPRequest`, etc.) where are all of these implemented? Are these API's implemented by each of browser themselves?

Comment: Have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API and don't confuse them with 3rd party API's like you'd find on eg. programmableweb.com

Comment: @yezzz Oh interesting I didn't know there were that many. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Yeah I just opened up the candy store for you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most objects and functions are either ECMA, W3C/DOM or other standards and specifications. Each browser vendor is responsible of implementing them.

For example, [`XMLHttpRequest` is a W3C standard.](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/)

Comment: I know this might be a little late but when these functions are executed are they executed in the JS runtime or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

> Are these API's implemented by each of browser themselves?

Yes.